# Is there a function to automatically generate cumulative area plot using matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, area

The following code using the matplotlib library gives us a simple area plot

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = range(1,6)
y = [1,2,3,4,3] 
plt.plot(x,y, labels=['A'])
```

Is there a function that can generate a cumulative area plot without having to transform y to:

```
y_cumulative = [1,3,6,10,13]
```

Thanks.

Comment: No, just call numpy.cumsum

Answer (score 0):

You can either use [`numpy.cumsum`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.cumsum.html), or write your own plain python function.

```
def cumsum(seq):
    """returns a list with the cumulative sum of seq
    """
    result = []
    current = 0
    for elt in seq:
        current += elt
        result.append(current)
    return result
```